# Manipulating data in keras custom loss function for CNN

Tags: numpy, keras, conv-neural-network, tensor, loss-function

I'm trying to write a custom loss function in Keras for a CNN I'm working on. Y_true and Y_pred will both be tensors of grayscale images, so I expect a shape of `[a, x, y, 1]`, where x and y are the dimensions of my images and a is the batch size.

The plan is to:

1. Threshold each image of Y_true by its mean pixel intensity
2. Use the non-zero elements of this mask to get an array of pixel values from Y_true and Y_pred
3. Measure the cosine similarity (using the built-in Keras loss function) of these arrays and return the average result of the batch as the loss

My main question is how I can efficiently implement this process?
Does the `cosine_similarity` function work on 1D arrays?

I know that I should avoid for loops to maintain efficiency but it's the only way I can think of implementing this function. Is there a more efficient way to implement this function using the Keras backend or numpy?

EDIT

Basic implementation and an unexpected error when compiling the model with this function:

```
def masked_cosine_similarity(y_true, y_pred):
    loss = 0
    for i in range(y_true.shape[0]):
        true_y = y_true[i,:,:,0]
        pred_y = y_pred[i,:,:,0]
        mask = true_y > np.mean(true_y)
        elements = np.nonzero(mask)
        true_vals = np.array([true_y[x,y] for x, y in zip(elements[0], elements[1])])
        pred_vals = np.array([pred_y[x,y] for x, y in zip(elements[0], elements[1])])
        loss += cosine_similarity(true_vals, pred_vals)
    return loss / y_true.shape[0]
```

Error message:

```
     64     loss = 0
---> 65     for i in range(y_true.shape[0]):
     66         true_y = y_true[i,:,:,0]
     67         pred_y = y_pred[i,:,:,0]

TypeError: 'NoneType' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The shape of a tensor in Keras/TF is usually `[None, height, width, channels]`.
This is due to the support of an arbitrary batch size, you don't want to build a model that only works for a specific batch size. For that reason, your code collapses on:

```
for i in range(y_true.shape[0]):
```

since `y_true.shape[0] == None`.

Why do you loop over the batch? You don't need to do it.
For example, given some element-wize loss function (MSE/cosine loss etc.) you can do something like:

```
def my_loss(y_true, y_pred):
    mask = tf.keras.backend.cast(y_true >= tf.math.reduce_mean(y_true, axis=[1,2], keepdims=True), 'float32') 
    masked_loss = K.sum(mask * elementwize_loss(y_true, y_pred), axis=-1)
    num_valid_pixels = K.maximum(1.0, K.cast(K.sum(mask), 'float32'))
    return masked_loss / num_valid_pixels
```

Comment: I've implemented your answer and am getting an `InvalidArgumentError: Incompatible shapes: [2,1024,1024,1] vs. [2,1024,1024]` which doesn't happen if I use a batch size of 1

Comment: it's possible that you use "channel_first"? please elaborate where exactly you get the error... if I must guess, maybe you need to add parameter "axis=-1" to the K.sum() operation.

Comment: In addition, I noticed you want to perform the mean per channel, so please view the edit to my original comment (specify axis=[1,2] to perform the mean for each example independently + add "keepdims=True" operator to keep the 4 dimension of the inputs).

Comment: Tried the updated code. Same error: `InvalidArgumentError:  Incompatible shapes: [8,1024,1024,1] vs. [8,1024,1024]`

Comment: A dummy example with the exact same code work for me, when setting the elementwize_loss to be a simple euclidean distance: (y_true-y_pred). My guess is that your implementation for cosine_similarity makes the last dimension (which is of value 1 and represent the single channel) disappear. try use reshape((-1, h,w,1)) or similar method to make sure you don't alter the number of dimensions.

Comment: Cosine similarity (as used here https://keras.io/api/losses/regression_losses/#cosinesimilarity-function) returns the loss when comparing structures, so it is probably a single numeric output rather than a tensor

Comment: You didn't answer the question - where does your code breaks, since the code I proposed works for euclidean loss. I won't debug your code so my last comment is to wonder why do you use cosine similarity?

Comment: cosine loss checks the correlation between vectors (and is mainly used in classification, after normalizing the latent vectors to be in unit scale). It is not designed for regression or comparing images. If for some reason you must use cosine similarity you can just multiply the mask both in y_pred and y_true before sending it to the cosine function (but in the case of cosine similarity it won't have the desired effect, since it will decrease the loss, and not just ignore invalid pixels, due to the "correlation" this function calculates, and this is true also for your original implementation).

Comment: I swapped cosine similarity for MSE in the custom loss function. It compiles the model without any issues, but fails when I try to fit the model to the data. The error is the same: `InvalidArgumentError: Incompatible shapes: [8,1024,1024,1] vs. [8,1024,1024]`

Comment: instead of using the keras mse function (which as you said, probably returns a scalar), try a simple elmentwize function: `masked_loss = K.square(mask * (y_true - y_pred))`.  set this in the suggested code above. that way, after normalizing in the number of valid pixels, you will get exactly "masked_mse" loss, as intended.

Comment: All working now. Thank you so much for helping me with the errors and understanding how a custom loss function should be implemented